# jquery .load() does not load external JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am loading external content into a div element using `jquery.load()` **without** a selector.  If the content loaded has embedded JS, the JS works as expected.  HOWEVER, if the content includes a script tag with `src=path-to-js-code` the js-code is not loaded.

Am I correct in this observation and if so is there a good solution other than embedding the JS in the loaded content?

**EDIT :**
A few clarifications and observations:

To load the content I am using

```
$("#DivId").load("path/to/content.php", CallbackFunction(response, status, xhr) {
    error checking and post processing code
});
```

Changing the load code to:

```
$.get("path/to/content.php", CallbackFunction(response, status, xhr) {
    error checking
    $("#DivId").html(response);
    post processing
});
```

Does not seem to change the behavior (more on the behavior below)

I have not tried parsing the response to retreive the script src and then using `getScript()`.

Now more on the behavior...

Using Firefox, it seems that the external JS is loaded but only if it has been about 2 min from the last load.  I do not see an attempt in Firebug unless the refresh is about 2m after the last load of the external JS. (weird).  When I was making JS code changes and hitting refresh, it was not loading my new code and thus the original question.

So i will withdraw my question in light of this clarified behavior (2m caching?).

Thanks.

Comment: Since you're using `load()` without a selector, it sounds like you're loading the content for the sole reason of executing a `<script>`. If so, why not use [`jQuery.getScript()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/)?

Comment: By "*without a selector*," are you referring to the [page fragment selector](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments)?

Comment: @user193130 - Not so easy with my current architecture.  The content to be loaded (html and JS) is generated dynamically on the server.  The php code was previously grabbing certain JS code from a DB table based on various data and embedding the JS into the returned content.  Recently i tried just having the script src= tag in the DB and the JS code in a file on the server (easier to edit).  But as posted, the external JS does not get loaded.

Comment: @Jonathan Lonowski - Yes correct.  I have read the "page fragment selector" will strip all script tags and thus even embedded JS is not loaded.  I wanted to point out I am NOT doing that.

Comment: @ds00424 Seems I misunderstood you. I thought you meant something like `jQuery().load('/path/to/content')` (which I'm not even sure would actually work) and that the HTML content being loaded wasn't being used except for the `<script>` contained therein.

Comment: Wondering if you've tried something like this instead of `load()`: `$.get('/path/to/content').done(function(data){$('#id').html(data);});` If that doesn't work, another idea is to output the script url via a custom HTTP header instead of inlining the `<script src="...">`, then pull the script URL out from the xhr object and call `$.getScript()` on it.

Answer (score 0):

Both the `.load()` and `.html()` jQuery methods utilise the `.innerHTML` property. This won't execute scripts added with `<script>` tag. Use a regular AJAX call e.g. `.get()` then in the callback use `.append()` to add your HTML string and the scripts will run once it's parsed e.g.

```
$.get("path/to/content.php", function(response, status, xhr) {
    // error checking
    $("#DivId").append(response); // Any <script> tags in the response string will execute
    // post processing
});
```

Thing is you need to make sure you're running trusted code if it's added by `.append()`

Comment: The docs mention .innerHtml in the "Loading Page Fragments" section where the return is parsed for only the section requested.  I am not doing that.  As mentioned in the edit, it seems the .load will load an external script, but only if it is 2m or older. (in FF) (no idea why that is).  And I have used .load() to load embedded scripts for a long time - so that works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering you can get the script src in the response text of `$.load` method with regular expressions, then use `$.getScript()` method to load the script, maybe something like this:

```
$("#DivId").load("path/to/content.php", function(response, status, xhr) {
    var regexp = new RegExp('script.*?src="(.*?)"'),
        execresults = regexp.exec(response);

    if(execresults.length > 1)
    {
        // the first result is the entire match including
        // the 'script..src=', so abandon it
        var matches = execresults.slice(1);

        $.each(matches, function(){
            $.getScript(this, function(){
                // do something after load script
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Hope this can help

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of a similar solution. However, I discovered that (at least in FF) the external JS seems to be only loaded if it is over 2 minutes old (at least it seems this way from testing and watching Firebug Net panel). I can deal with that. My post was prompted when during testing I was hitting refresh and not seeing the changed JS code get loaded. But after waiting 2m and hitting refresh, it was then loaded. Go figure.

Comment: Could it be the cache problem? what about adding a random number as query string after the script url? like`$.getScript(this + '?rand=' + Math.random(), function() {});`

Answer (score 0):

This is the easy way to load an external JS to your jQuery

```
 $.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: "path/to/content.php",
 dataType: "script"
 success:CallbackFunction(response, status, xhr)     
 });
```

Comment: Based on the arch/design, the content loaded is a mix of HTML, CSS and scripts.